# Serving customers algorithm

Tags: algorithms, queueing-theory

Well I have a problem with a Christmas assignment and my teacher is not responding(maybe he is skiing somewhere now) so I will need some help.

The algorithm is about an office and the waiting time of the customers. We have one office that has to serve $n$ customers $a_1, a_2,\cdots ,a_n$. We assume that serving time $t(a_j)$ for  each customer $a_j$ is known. Let $a_j$ to be served after $k$ customers $a_{i_{1}},a_{i_{2}},\cdots ,a_{i_{k}}$.  His waiting time $T(a_j)$ is equal to

$$T(a_j) = t(a_{i_{1}})+t(a_{i_{2}})+\cdots +t(a_{i_{k}})+t(a_{j})$$

I want to an efficient algorithm that will compute the best way to serve in order to reduce the total waiting time.

$$\sum_{j=1}^nT(a_j)$$

My first thought is that the customers with the smallest serving time have to go first and the obvious solution is apply a sorting algorithm.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what is the difference between $t(a_{i_{2}})$ and $t(a_{{2}})$? does the (i) subscript denote the serving clerk or queue for example?

Comment: @Emmad: I'd assume that the labels $a_1$ to $a_n$ have been assigned to the customers in advance, and we're to choose a permutation $i_1, \dotsc, i_n$ of $1, \dotsc, n$ so as to minimize the total waiting time as defined above.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, serving the customers in ascending order of serving time is optimal.

To prove this, note that, if the customers are served in the order $a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, \dotsc, a_{i_n}$ and if $t(a_{i_j}) > t(a_{i_{j+1}})$ for any $1 \le j < n$, then swapping the order of the customers $a_{i_j}$ and $a_{i_{j+1}}$ reduces the total waiting time by $t(a_{i_j}) - t(a_{i_{j+1}}) > 0$ time units.

Comment: This is a special case of [rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) (where $y_i = i$)

Answer (score 1):

Problems of this kind belong to the area of operations research known as scheduling problems (scheduling theory). Here is a short bibliography of books that deal with this topic: http://www.york.cuny.edu/~malk/biblio/scheduling2-biblio.html There is a lot of nice mathematics involved.